No module named 'cmake' (Jupyter notebook cmake, dlib import)
I'm doing face detection using a real-time camera, but I keep getting stuck in dlib install.
The usage environment is Windows and jupyter notebook.
**!pip install dlib !pip install opencv-python**
I searched and tried the methods one by one (I also received help from ai), but the following error keeps popping up.
cmake is said to be already installed, whether you check it in cmd or jupyter notebook.
However, dlib install says that the cmake module cannot be found.
Some people say that they succeeded by installing dlib directly into c:, but I tried that method but it doesn't work.
I thought it was a problem with the cmake environment variable, so even if I installed cmake directly from the site and set the environment variable, it didn't work.
If you have any guesses about the problem or solution, please feel free to reply...!!

You need to restart kernel after you install packages for them to be seen. Press on >> or from kernel -> restart kernel.

Thank you!! It worked when I restarted the kernel!
